# How do I replace a belongs_to association without changing the original class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, rails-activerecord, refinerycms

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Refinery::Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: '::Refinery::User', foreign_key: :user_id

  # SNIP very long class body
end
```

I don't want to override the whole class if I can help it, as there's a ton of behavior there that should remain intact, and many other parts of the engine reference the class by name so I can't subclass it.  Is there any way using `class_eval` to remove or replace an existing association?  I tried just redefining it like this:

```
Refinery::Base::Post.class_eval do
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'MyUser', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you use send instead of class eval and see if it works? class_eval will eval that code in eigen class context in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the initializer file, which I think is in config/initializers/refinery/blog.rb

```
Refinery::Blog.configure do |config|


  # If you're grafting onto an existing app, change this to your User class
   Refinery::Blog.user_class = 'MyUser'
end
```

Comment: No luck.  That option is in the git repo, but not in the most recent version (currently 2.0.4).

Comment: Huh. It looks like the commit where that change was added is fairly small; could you patch it in?